# Lanzamiento de dados en C++

Tags: c++

Necesito un programa que realize lo siguiente:

- Lance dos dados (entre 1 y 6).
- Si el valor es igual láncelos de nuevo.
- Imprima el número total de casillas que avanza el jugador

A continuación tengo el código; sin embargo, no logro encontrar una función `if` o similar que pueda lanzarlos de nuevo si ambos valores son iguales.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

int input (int cant)
{
  if (cant == 1)
    {
      std::cout << "Presione \"ENTER\" para lanzar el dado 1";
    }
  else
    {
      std::cout << "Presione \"ENTER\" para lanzar el dado 2";
    }
  std::cin.ignore ();
}


int tirardado ()
{
  int ran;
  srand (time (0));
  ran = rand () % 6 + 1;
  std::cout << "Obtuvo " << ran << std::endl;
  return ran;
}


int dado (int pdado, int sdado)
{
  std::cout << "Ha avanzado " << pdado + sdado << " casillas" << std::endl;
  return pdado + sdado;
}



int main ()
{
  int total, primerdado, segundodado;

  input (1);
  primerdado = tirardado ();
  input (2);
  segundodado = tirardado ();
  total = dado(primerdado, segundodado);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No conozco muy a fondo C++, pero se me ocurre que puedes declarar una variable en ámbito global que guarde la última tirada y luego solo tienes que comparar si la tirada actual es igual o no a la vieja ya guardada, después de cada tirada y del if, tienes que volver a asignar el valor de la vieja tirada a la actual para que a la siguiente vuelta esté actualizado su valor.

Comment: Te recomiendo que reescribas tu pregunta imaginando cómo es que otros podrían beneficiarse de lo que preguntas. El título actual no dice mucho sobre el problema que encuentras. Por la respuesta de Paula, asumo que el problema es que los números "aleatorios" que recibes son siempre iguales. ¿es correcto? De ser así, ese es el título que puedes poner para que otros puedan beneficiarse de tu pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No uses `rand`.

Estás programando en C++, sin embargo sigues paradigmas de C y usas utilidades de dicho lenguaje; no uses [`rand`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) pues no forma parte de la especificación de C++ y en consecuencia puede no ser portable y puede ofrecer resultados y rendimiento cuestionables. Por ello [se está estudiando deprecarlo](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3924.pdf).

A partir del estándar C++11 el lenguaje C++ ofrece una completa librería de [generación de números pseudoaleatorios](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) que permite escoger la [distribución de probabilidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_de_probabilidad) (uniforme, Bernoulli, Poisson, normal, discreta, constante, lineal...), el tipo subyacente del valor generado e incluso el algoritmo a usar (minstd, mt19937, ranlux, knuth...).

#### Estás falseando la distribución.

La distribución numérica de `std::rand` es homogénea entre `0` y [`RAND_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX), esto significa que cualquier número dentro de dicho rango tiene las mismas probabilidades de ser esogido (1 entre `RAND_MAX`).

Al hacer módulo (`%`) sobre el resultado de `std::rand` rompes la homogeneidad si el divisor no es múltiplo de `RAND_MAX`. Suponiendo un `RAND_MAX` de `32767` con un módulo sobre `6` obtenemos que los números del `1` al `5` tienen una probabilidad de aparición menor que el `0` (un 0,003% menor).

#### Propuesta.

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, podrías crear un objeto dado que incluyera una distribución homogénea de valores entre 1 y 6:

```
template <int MIN, int MAX>
struct Dado
{
    int lanzar()
    {
        /* Generamos un número pseudo-aleatorio con el algoritmo
        mt19937 distribuido uniformemente entre MIN y MAX */
        return distribucion(generador);
    }

private:
    // Tenemos control sobre el algoritmo y distribución a usar.
    std::random_device device;
    std::mt19937 generador{device()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion{MIN, MAX};
};
```

Con ese objeto `Dado` puedes crear una función que siga tus premisas:

- Lanzar dos dados de 6 caras.
- Si el valor es igual lanzarlos de nuevo.

```
// Alias de dado de 6 caras.
using D6 = Dado<1, 6>;
// Nuestros dados.
D6 dado1, dado2;

int tirada()
{
    int tirada1, tirada2, avances{};

    do
    {
        avances += (tirada1 = dado1.lanzar()) + (tirada2 = dado2.lanzar());
        std::cout << "Primer dado: " << tirada1
            << "\nSegundo dado: " << tirada2
            << "\n\tAvances: " << avances << '\n';
    } while (tirada1 == tirada2);

    return avances;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5gUXjeWpicYwNS28)</kbd>.

Comment: Creo que deberías escribir una pregunta/respuesta sobre este tema y enlazar a la misma... es un tema demasiado recurrente :)

Answer (score 3):

> no logro encontrar una función if o similar que pueda lanzarlos de nuevo si ambos valores son iguales.

Eso es porque no has probado a almacenar el código en una función independiente:

```
bool TirarDados()
{
  input (1);
  primerdado = tirardado ();
  input (2);
  segundodado = tirardado ();
  total = dado(primerdado, segundodado);
  return primerdado == segundodado;
}

int main()
{
  if( TirarDados() ) // Primera tirada
    TirarDados();    // Segunda tirada... solo si son iguales
}
```

Claro que también podrías hacerlo con un bucle:

```
int main()
{
  int contador = 0; // Para garantizar que solo repetimos la tirada una vez
  do
  {
    input (1);
    primerdado = tirardado ();
    input (2);
    segundodado = tirardado ();
    total = dado(primerdado, segundodado);
    contador++;
  } while( primerdado == segundodado && contador == 1);
}
```

Por cierto, nota que la función de impresión se puede simplificar bastante. Además no devuelve ningún valor, luego su tipo de retorno debería ser `void`:

```
void input (int cant)
{
  std::cout "Presione \"ENTER\" para lanzar el dado " << cant;
  std::cin.ignore ();
}
```

Además, ten en cuenta que la inicialización del generador de números aleatorios únicamente es necesario hacerlo una vez, sería recomendable que esa inicialización la movieses al `main`:

```
int main()
{
  srand (time (0));
  // ...
}
```

Además, desde C++11 (recordemos que es un estándar que data de 2011) está disponible la librería [random](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), que pone a tu disposición un mecanismo para generar números aleatorios mucho más seguro y potente y versátil que `rand()`, que es una función heredada de C.